# execCommand() replaces the url with ../

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

I'm insert an image url to my wysiwyg, but Firefox somehow is replacing my url with ../

```
string += "<img src='"+encodeURI(domain)+"/"+file_name+"' id='"+filename+"'>";
console.log(string);
```

Console logs this:

```
<img src='http://www.testing.com/web_graph.gif' id='web_graph.gif'>
```

then using

```
document
  .getElementById("texto_a_editar")
  .contentWindow
  .document
  .execCommand('inserthtml', false, string);
```

I get this:

```
<img src="../web_graph.gif" id="web_graph.gif">
```

What should I do to have the complete url instead?

Comment: This is a terribly annoying problem. I think I remember it's been discussed on SO already, maybe under the heading of CKEditor

Comment: If this is about CKEditor, as Pekka said, then you *should* be able to fix this problem by setting the BaseHref preference.

Comment: thanks for replies, no, this isn't CKEditor, its my try of make a wysiwyg.

Comment: BaseHref is indeed the answer, I had to change some other files because of that, but it solves the 'bug'.

Answer (score 0):

```
var completeURI = location.href,
    completeURIi = location.href.lastNidexOf("/"),
    img = document.getElementById("web_graphic.gif").getAttribute("src");
    img = img.substr(img.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    completeURI = completeURI.substr(0, completeURI.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + img;
```